# How to do a Select from a table row and retrieve data less than 30 days?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table (Mysql) called Computers

In this table I have two columns (see pic)

[image]

How can I do a select so it only shows me computers whose last contacts were less than 30 days ago?

Comment: you should add  data sample as text not as image  ..

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Comment: You might look into MySQL's DATEDIFF() and NOW() functions.

Comment: Please share your SQL query you have tired to get the desire result.

Answer (score 0):

Try This-

```
SELECT * FROM Computers
WHERE `Last Contact` >= date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```